# Reason for defining a vector as a $(1,0)$ tensor

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

I'm reading Jeevanjee's "An Introduction to Tensors and Group Theory for Physicists" and have come across the following definition of a $(r,s)$ tensor: a map $T:V\times\ldots\times V$ ($r$ times) $\times V^* \times\ldots\times V^*$ ($s$ times) $\to \mathbb{C}$ that is linear in each argument. I can understand that dual vectors are $(1,0)$ tensors, but

> vectors can be viewed as $(0,1)$ tensors as follows:
>   $$v(f) \equiv f(v)$$where $v \in V$ and $f \in V^*$.

What's the intuition or reasoning behind this roundabout definition? Why forcibly define a vector as a tensor? I guess I'm confused because I'm very much used to the idea of a dual vector as something that eats a vector and outputs a scalar. What's the need to turn it around and define a vector as something that eats a dual vector? Does this have anything to do with the equivalence between a vector and its double dual counterpart, and we're just implicitly assuming the element from $V^{**}$ that corresponds to $v$ as $v$ itself?

Comment: We know that a vector space is isomorphic to its double dual. Hence, this is exactly what's been done here. A $(0,1)$ tensor is a functional from $V^*\to \Bbb{R}$, and hence an element of the double dual, which is isomorphic to a vector.

Comment: The reason behind this could be the fact that because tensors are inherently functionals on vector spaces, we have to define vectors in terms of functionals. And this is the "best" we can do.

Comment: @fierydemon Actually, this is not the "best". Modern definition of tensors doesn't define them as functionals, but rather as elements of tensor products of vector spaces. With this definition, $(0,1)$-tensors are naturally vectors, without requiring finite dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your suspicion that this works only for finite-dimensional $V$, where the natural map $V \rightarrow V^{**}$ is an isomorphism. In general, this map is injective, but $V^{**}$ is *much* bigger.

Concerning the profit of this definition, have a look at the construction of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ from integers $\mathbb Z$ - we then say that an integer is now a rational number of the form ${n\over 1}$, that is, integers get naturally embedded into rationals, which is extremely useful. The same happens here: we define tensors in terms of vectors and linear forms (dual vectors), but then it happens that both vectors and forms are instances of tensors. Thus, you can talk about tensors in general, and this will apply to vectors, too (e.g. define tensor fields, Lie or covariant derivatives, etc).

---

To be honest, I consider this definition of tensors (as multilinear maps) somewhat...outdated. A slightly more modern approach talks about tensor products of vector spaces $V \otimes U$, and then a tensor over a vector space $V$ of covariant degree $n$ and contravariant degree $m$ is simply an element of $V \otimes \dots \otimes V \otimes V^* \otimes \dots \otimes V^*$ (where $V$ appears $m$ times and $V^*$ appears $n$ times). Thus, if $n=0$ and $m=1$, we get simply $V$ - the original space of vectors.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the tensor product definition too. That's why all this is so confusing, especially in the context of Physics. In the book I mentioned, the definition I specified in the question is called the "modern component-free definition". By that standard, the outdated definition is the one in which tensors are defined to be objects whose components transform in a specific way under a change of basis.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Well, yes, unfortunately physics is very conservative when it comes to adopting modern mathematical notions. Defining tensors as functionals is already a huge step forward (at least, it makes everything coordinate-free and hence much easier).